# Word or phrase describing on/off state

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, word-usage, phrase-requests, expression-choice

English is not my primary language so I have hard time with this problem. I am currently writing comments to computer code. There is setting that enable/disable some functionality. What would be correct comment to this? Is there noun form of word enable? The comment would be something like:

`Sets ??? of functionality.`

I am thinking about:

`Sets working state of functionality.`

`Sets turning on/off of functionality.`

`Sets availability of functionality.`

But it just seems wrong. Is there some better words that could describe this?

Comment: Tangentially: Be wary of terse comments in code -- you'll need the meaning later. For example, "If `true`, then _____. If `false`, then _____."  Oftentimes in code, true/false settings are not exactly opposite in the outcome.

Comment: *Sets* / *resets* functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write

> *enables* or *disables* the functionality

or

> *activates* or *deactivates* the functionality

or, less comprehensibly

> *toggles* the operation of the functionality

Comment: Thank you. 'enables or disables the functionality' suits me, cannot believe I didn't think of that. Well I should think harder next time :)

Answer (score 0):

A part of me thinks, in certain contexts, the word "parity" would work here.

"Toggles the parity of the machine state."

Comment: Which definition of parity are you using?